# Mailing functionality using node.js's nodemailer fails in openshift

Tags: node.js, sendmail, openshift

I have an issue with nodemailer support in openshift. I created a simple node.js application that sends a mail using nodemailer, following the hello world example given in **https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer**

The mail is sent from a gmail id to two other gmail ids. This functionality is invoked while rendering the home page of my application. It worked well when the node.js application was run locally. I created a node js application in openshift and tested the application locally. I worked well. But on deploying the app to open shift, the mailing functionality failed, though the home page was rendered properly.

Is this mailing feature supported in openshift? Or am I missing something, like some extra configuration that is required in openshift for enabling this mailing support?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this should work ... can you try changing the port # you are using -- say try 587 with TLS in the 
wellknown.js configuration. See if that works.

The other thing to check is that your email provider allows authenticated connections from Amazon AWS EC2 hosts.

HTH